# Timer is giving interrupt in half of the expected time

Tags: timer, pic, mplab

I am using MPLAB in simulator mode. I had generated source files using "mplab code configurator" in mplab, and I have selected oscillator as "hfint1" with frequency as 8 mhz.

Timer 0 has configured for 10 sec (Triggering interrupt), but when I am running the code, I observed in "Stop watch" that interrupt has generated after 5 sec only. If I take timer 0 for 20 sec, then interrupt is generated for 10 sec. Can any one tell me the exact reason, why it is happening.

Comment: Be sure you have set the corret instruction frequency under Project Properties / Simulator. IF you have a PIC16 PIC18 switch it to 2MHz (default is 1 MHz)

Comment: Instruction frequency is impacting the timer0 in simulator mode, but still in stop watch i am not able to get the exact time duration by switching to 2 MHz.

Comment: I guess the problem is the clock source, It should be Fosc/4. This means `T0CS = 010`in `T0CON1`  Please check

Comment: It's working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You had to select the right clock source for your timer with the `T0SC` bits in `T0CON`.

If you want to clock you timer with Fosc/4 T0SC should be 010.

This means:

```
T0CON1bits.T0SC = 0b010;
```